# HowTo define a HarvestDirectory element in a library (WixLib) so the Wix projects associated with the library does not need to implement it?

Tags: reference, wix, heat, wixlib

We've defined a conditional setup with few main projects and a central library. No when we try to harvest a directory in a library (WixLib) the ComponentGroupName "reference" goes unresolved.

On the WixLib:

````
```<HarvestDirectory Include="($sys.CurDir)sistema\saludos">
  <DirectoryRefId>SaludosDir</DirectoryRefId>
  <ComponentGroupName>SaludosCompGroup</ComponentGroupName>
  <PreprocessorVariable>var.preVar</PreprocessorVariable>
</HarvestDirectory>```
````

Any reference to Component goes unresolved:

```
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="fooLibraryItems"/>
         <ComponentGroup Id="fooLibraryItems" Directory="INSTALLDIR" >
         <ComponentGroupRef Id ="SaludosCompGroup" />
         <ComponentGroupRef Id ="DespedidasCompGroup"/>
      </ComponentGroup>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please share a build log and the contents of the generated WXS file?

Comment: I'm sorry @B.Murri, that part of the project was put on hold and I don't have now the logs. As soon as I return to this I'll post them here. Thanks any way.